# Unable to add multiple pages to the pdf using pdfmaker

Tags: html2canvas, pdfmake

I am new to pdfmaker and I have a data around 15 pages,  when i render my html div it always displays a single page unable to iterate all data onto the pdf..

Any help will be appreciated thanks..

downloadAllClaims(){

```
var content = [];
var pdfElements = document.getElementsByClassName("myTable");
for (var i = 0; i < pdfElements.length; i++) {
        html2canvas(<HTMLElement>pdfElements[i]).then(canvas => {
          var data = canvas.toDataURL();

             return content.push({
                image: data,
                width: 500,
                // pageBreak: 'after'
            });
            
        })
}
```

Comment: what does it have to do with angular or angularjs?

Comment: Sorry!! I was using it in my angular application.